# Show that $\sin(x)$ is a subset of $\sin^2(x)$ when they are Rational Numbers

Tags: elementary-set-theory, rational-numbers

Consider the sets

$$
\begin{split}
A &= \left\{x\in \mathbb R\mid\sin(x)\in \mathbb Q\right\} \\
B &= \left\{x\in\mathbb R\mid\sin^2(x)\in \mathbb Q\right\}
\end{split}
$$

Why is $A\subseteq B$?

The main confusion for me is that when $\sin(x)$ is a rational number it can be negative, but $\sin^2(x)$ only has positive value right?

Comment: @Henrik Sorry about the confusion, but this question was a revision question from my lecturer and I checked multiple times to make sure it is sin^2(x)....

Comment: The square of a rational number is a rational number!

Comment: Also note that the inclusion is strict, consider $\pi/4$ radians.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so $A$ is the set of all real numbers with rational sine. Let $x \in A$, then $\sin x \in \mathbb{Q}$. Then, $\exists a,b \in \mathbb{Z}$ with $b\ne 0$ such that
$\sin x = \frac{a}{b}$.

In that case,
$$
\sin^2 x = \left( \sin x \right)^2 = \left(\frac{a}{b} \right)^2
 = \frac{a^2}{b^2} \in \mathbb{Q},
$$
since $a^2, b^2 \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $b^2 \ne 0$ (can you prove it?)

Thus, $x \in B$ as well...

Comment: I still cannot get my head around the possible values of negative a,b ,when that occurs sin^2 x cannot cover the values in sinx right? Or am I missing something...

Comment: @CookieJar you are :) if $\sin x = a/b < 0$ then $\sin^2 x = a^2/b^2 > 0$  but it is still rational!

Comment: @CookieJar in $B$ there are (much) more elements. I mean $A$ is strictly included in $B$. Think to $\frac{\pi}{3}$ it is in $B$ but not in $A$. Or simply $\arcsin \sqrt{a}$ for all $a$ which are not perfect squares

Answer (score 0):

If $x\in A$ then $\sin(x)=a/b$ for some $a,b\in\mathbb{N}$. Thus
$
\sin^2(x)=a^2/b^2
$
And since both $a^2,b^2\in\mathbb{N}$ we conclude that $\sin^2(x)\in\mathbb{Q}$ and so $x\in B$.